# How could I create two UIViews and have a swipe gesture to mask one over the other?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, swipe

So I am trying to mask a `UIView` over another one which will ideally appear once the swipe gesture has happened. There are a lot of libraries / example code out there I have come across that allow you to slide in a `UIView` which would appear on top, but it should really be masking over the first view, rather than simply overlaying it. There is most likely a simple elegant solution for this, but so far there is very little I have seen that supports this kind of animation. Image below helps describe the ideal solution:

[image]

Comment: If i understood correctly, the two views should not move, there should be only some sort of transparency line, (opaque on left and transparent on the right) that you would swipe. Is that it?

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right. As long as both views can still function (with buttons like above etc...) but not actually move, just be masked over each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gist time:
https://gist.github.com/mnmaraes/9529586

The magic happens at:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat xDelta = scrollView.contentOffset.x;

    self.topView.center = CGPointMake(self.topCenterInitialX + xDelta, self.topView.center.y);
}
```

So to explain better. You have a `bottomView` and a `topView` which are exactly the same, except the colors are switched. The `topView` is contained in a `clipperView` which is inside a `UIScrollView` (To handle panning and swiping). So when you scroll right/left the `topView` moves the opposite direction giving the impression that it is stationary, the excess is then clipped by `clipperView`. Anyways, it's all there. Let me know if you don't understand something.

Have fun!

Comment: excellent solution. Does this work if UIView's have subviews ?

Comment: Yes. The example in the gist has one subview and that too gets color swapped.

Comment: This is unreal! It's worked perfectly and is a very elegant solution. Thanks.